# Selecting ticketid with status history

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I'm trying to select tickets that had status that are currently open (ie on Hold, Pending suppliers, In progress) with a specific ticket class ='SR' between 2 dates (1 April 2015 - 30 April 2015).

```
select * from tkt_table where class = 'SR' and status = 'INPROG' or status = 'PENDING' or status = 'INC'... order date by datereport desc
```

There are two tables, the one that has ticket information is `tkt_table` and the other one has the ticket status history `tktStatus_table`.  they both have `tktid` as key.

How do I get this SQL statement to show me all of the tickets that had the statuses changed between a selected date(1 April - 30April)

Many thanks :)

Table on left is **tkt_table** and right is **tkt_status**

[image: tkt_table]
[image: tkt_status]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COUNT(DISTINCT status) in the having clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
tkt_table t inner join 
(SELECT tktid, count(distinct status) cnt FROM tktStatus_table 
 WHERE dateReport >= '20150401' AND dateReport < '20150501'
 GROUP BY tktid 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) > 1) as a on t.tktid=a.tktid
```

Comment: Thanks Cha,  I am trying to get how many times the status has been changed on each ticketid, where the ticket status has been open (INPROG, HOLD, PEND, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` both the table and then `Group By` Ticket Id

```
SELECT tiketId from tkt_table tt JOIN  tktStatus_table  ts on tt.tiketId = ts.tiketId
where Class = 'SR' and dateReport Between '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
Group BY tktid
Having Count(DISTINCT status) > 1
```